# Get Session from HttpActionContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a permission attribute to configure in each action of my controllers so this custom attribute should take the sessionId from the user.
My code is like that:

```
public class PermissionChecker: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private int _permissionId { get; set; }
    private IUserSelectorService _userService { get; set; }

    public PermissionChecker(int permissionId)
    {
        _permissionId = permissionId;
        _userService = new UserSelectorService();
    }

    public PermissionChecker(int permissionId, IUserSelectorService userService)
    {
        _permissionId = permissionId;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (_userService.HasPermission(_permissionId, /* here I must pass the session["Id"]*/)){
             base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
             return;
        }
        throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if(filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
    {
      var id = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Id"];          
    }
}
```

**EDIT** 
Given the fact that you're using MVC 4 and you don't have

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

Try using

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Comment: I'm using MVC4 so there is no override with ActionExecutingContext

Comment: Ok. I assume that actionContext doesn't have a property HttpContext which would allow you to access the Session

Comment: Try using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session

Comment: Ok. Have a go at it. Remember to mark as "answered" if it helped :)

Comment: I was using ActionFilterAttribute of System.Web.Http.Filters and not of System.Web.Mvc, because of this HttpActionContext was used. Thank.

Comment: Can somebody please help with my question related to this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504355/actionexecutingcontext-httpcontext-session-is-null]

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access using ActionFilterAttribute then OnActionExecting event it wont give the accessibility of HttpContext with System.Web.Http.

Instead of that If you are trying to access using System.Web.Mvc it will provide you the current session with onActionExecting event with help of ActionExecutingContext class.