# ActionExecutingContext HttpContext.Session is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I am using MVC Actionfilter (Global) to call db to get user data and i try to store that in session.
Coding as mentioned in [Dependency Injection in ASP.net Session_Start method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852440/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-session-start-method/32854222#32854222).
Everything works fine in local machine.

But in production machine, my filterContext.HttpContext.Session (filterContext being ActionExecutingContext) is always null.

I dont know what more information i can give, but if somebody asks questions I am ready to provide more answers.

Please let me know what i can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the below to the web.config fixed the problem, although i dont know why it has to be done.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="Session" />
    <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```